# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/****/public_html/get_data_id.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, json

Im having a problem I did a research and common problem is lack of semi colon but I am sure that there's nothing wrong in my code
please check this out.

```
    <?php
require 'connection.php';
 
$query = "select id from `account_info`";
 
$res = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
 
$result = array();
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id'=>$row[0]
));
}
 
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 
mysqli_close($connect);
 
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php 

define('hostname','mysql.hostinger.ph');
define('user','********_mftis');
define('password','********');
define('databaseName','u366906409_mftis');
$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,user,password,databaseName);
?>
```

Comment: Wrap off quotes from `table and column` name instead use backtick

Comment: did you try this  , remove Double quote from account_info in Query

Comment: @Saty is correct and the error there will be revealed as soon as this is fixed, however the quoted error is most likely coming from  a syntax error in `connection.php` . Can you share that code as well?

Comment: I tried removing the double quotes.. still not working

Comment: Quick note: you select `*` but only gets what seems to be the id column. It would be (arguably) better to just select the id then...

Comment: Your issue resides in code that you haven't posted or that got mangled when copy'n'pasting (wrong file/version, Unicode chars, etc).

Comment: I suggest you have a file corruption of some sort. Recode your `connection.php` or just copy/paste it into a new file and then rename it. If that does not work, do the same to the main code

Answer (score 0):

write your query as

```
$query = "select * from 'account_info'";
```

Comment: Not related to the Actual error in the Actual question

Comment: tried that but still getting the same error